# How can I add private fields in Freezed data classes?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to add private fields in [Freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) data class.

So, I tried to write this.

```
@freezed
class User with _$User {
  const factory User(
    String _id,
    String _name,
  ) = _User;
}
```

However, In my editor, displayed "Named parameters can't start with an underscore.(private_optional_parameter)" in user.freezed.dart

Please tell me what I solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make [Adnan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12555423/adnan)'s solution more visible:

You can protect fields in the `freezed` class by annotation them with `@protected`:

```
@freezed
class User with _$User {
  const factory User(
    @protected String id,
    @protected String name,
  ) = _User;
}
```

Of course this is only semi-useful unless you also define some getters to access the information from the protected fields.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to have a private property with a public getter that return modified variable, and using `@Default('')` would not solve my case of *casting* nullable type to sound type.

Anyway - long story short: **freezed (as per ver. 2.4.5) by default does not allow private properties in its classes** due to code generation issues with `copyWith` method. If that method is not important to you, then you can tell `build_runner` to skip it by annotating your class like so:

```dart
part 'user.freezed.dart';

@Freezed(copyWith: false)
class User with _$User {
  const factory User(String _id, String _name) = _User;
}
```

Then your properties will be inaccessible to other classes (but you could not use `copyWith` method on `User` object). Marking your code with `@protected` annotation is not so great as your variables are still exposed and visible.

For my case I had to find workaround. I leave code snippet here as someone might need that in future (might as well be future me):

```dart
part 'user.freezed.dart';

@freezed
class User with _$User {
  //private constructor with exposed and generated public properties
  const factory User._(String id, String name) = _User;

  //public constructor modifying those values
  factory User(String? id, String? name) {
    return User._(id ?? 'you dont have id' name ?? '');
  }
}
```